# Is there a way to nest an ExpandableListView inside of a RelativeLayout?

Tags: java, android, layout, android-layout, expandablelistview

What I would like to do is create a Layout with buttons, edittexts, an textviews on the left side, and have the ExpandableListView on the right. Is there any way to do this? I have googled, but I haven't really come up with anything. Does anyone have any bright ideas, or do you know the solution I am looking for?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to an example with two ListViews inside one RelativeLayout. This should be the same if they're expandable or not.

[How to use Two ListView in one screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395336/how-to-use-two-listview-in-one-screen)